# 翻訳APIを入れるjsを書くとrequire is not definedが表示され、javascriptが動作しない

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qiitaに載っていた、こちらの記事を参考に
Microsoft Translator APIを入れようと思っています。
[参照記事](http://qiita.com/kemayako/items/21fe36005e6e729aff77)

```
    'use strict';

var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var qs = require('querystring');

getAccessToken(function (token) {
    translate(token, '翻訳したい文章', function (translated) {
        console.log(translated);
    });
});

function getAccessToken(callback) {
    var body = '';
    var req = https.request({
        host: 'datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net',
        path: '/v2/OAuth2-13',
        method: 'POST'
    }, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        }).on('end', function () {
            var resData = JSON.parse(body);
            callback(resData.access_token);
        });
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    var data = {
        'client_id': 'クライアントIDに設定した文字列',
        'client_secret': '顧客の秘密に設定した文字列',
        'scope': 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    };

    req.write(qs.stringify(data));
    req.end();
}

function translate(token, text, callback) {
    var options = 'appId=Bearer ' + token + '&to=en&text=' + text +
            '&oncomplete=translated';
    var body = '';
    var req = http.request({
        host: 'api.microsofttranslator.com',
        path: '/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?' + qs.escape(options),
        method: 'GET'
    }, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        }).on('end', function () {
            eval(body);
        });
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    req.end();

    function translated(text) {
        callback(text);
    }
}
```

上記のコードをjsファイルに追記すると、
consoleエラーで

```
require is not defined
```

と表示されます。

この問題で他のメソッドもconsole.logが反応しない状態になっています。

Qiitaの記事ではhtmlファイルまでは載っていなかったのですが、
何かあらかじめ宣言しておく必要があるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: これnode.jsじゃないですか？

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザ上で動くJavascriptではなく、サーバサイドで動くJavaScriptですね。
サーバサイドで動くJavaScriptなのでサーバサイドで動作させるための環境が必要です。

commonJSやnode.jsのキーワードで検索してみてください。いろいろと参考になるサイトがヒットすると思います。

Comment: nodeではなく、プラウザで動かすのはできない感じですかね？

Comment: できません。他の方が提示されているようにMicrosoft Translator APIを使う別のサンプルを参考にしたほうが良いと思います。

Comment: なるほどです。参考にしてみます。

Answer (score 0):

ブラウザで動かすコードではないので別のサンプルコードを探したほうが早いかもしれません。例えば [第38回　使ってみようMicrosoft Translator：使ってみよう！ Windows Live SDK/API｜gihyo.jp … 技術評論社](http://gihyo.jp/dev/serial/01/wl-sdk/0038)